# how to use type correctly in a function?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write numerical methods for calculating the integral

```
module NumericalMethods(
  trapezoidal_method
) where

type Func = Double -> Double
type Interval = [Double]
type N = Integer 

trapezoidal_method:: Func -> Interval -> N -> Double
trapezoidal_method f interval n = h*((f (head interval) + f $ tail interval)/2 + sum_fxs)
                                  where
                                    h :: Double
                                    h = (tail interval - head interval) / fromIntegral n 
                                    sum_fxs = sum fxs
                                    fxs = map f [head interval + h * fromIntegral x | x <- [1..n-1]]
```

I get this error:

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘Double -> Double’ with actual type ‘Double’ 
• Possible cause: ‘f’ is applied to too many arguments
    In the first argument of ‘(+)’, namely ‘f (head interval)’
    In the first argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘f (head interval) + f’
    In the first argument of ‘(/)’, namely ‘(f (head interval) + f $ tail interval)’
    | 
 10 | trapezoidal_method f interval n = h*((f (head interval) + f $ tail interval)/2 + sum_fxs)
    |                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: I'm not sure about the error, but `f $ tail interval` is certainly wrong, since `tail interval` is `[Double]`, not a `Double`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One issue is your use of `$` in `f (head interval) + f $ tail interval`.

The `$` operator has the lowest precedence of almost everything, so it will be interpreted as `(f (head interval) + f) $ (tail interval)`. It is trying to figure out what you mean with `f (head interval) + f`.

You probably just want to use parentheses: `f (head interval) + f (tail interval)`.

---

A second issue is your use of lists for intervals. I think tuples would be more suitable:

```
type Interval = (Double, Double)
```

Then you can use `fst` and `snd` instead of the erroneous `head` and `tail`:

```
trapezoidal_method:: Func -> Interval -> N -> Double
trapezoidal_method f interval n = h*((f (fst interval) + f (snd interval))/2 + sum_fxs)
  where
    h :: Double
    h = (snd interval - fst interval) / fromIntegral n 
    sum_fxs = sum fxs
    fxs = map f [fst interval + h * fromIntegral x | x <- [1..n-1]]
```

Comment: Better yet, since `interval` is never used except as an argument to `fst` or `snd`, just pattern-match to get the two components. `trapezoidal_method f (low, high) n = ...`